# MongoClient.connect(connectionURL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, client) => { ^TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient

const connectionURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
const databaseName = 'task-manager'

MongoClient.connect(connectionURL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, client) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.log('Unable to connect to database!')
}

const db = client.db(databaseName)

})
```

follwing error occurs
MongoClient.connect(connectionURL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, client) => {     ^TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined

Comment: If `mongodb.MongoClient` is undefined, did you try debugging/logging/whatever to find out what `mongodb` _is_?

Comment: What is the version of `mongodb` package ?

Comment: Your subject should provide a summary of the problem rather than the raw output of the error message.

Comment: version is 4.4 for mongodb